# Creating variables in a systematical way using loops in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, for-loop

Is there? Like Let's say I need 5 variables in ActionScript 3.0 and would like to name them as follows:

```
var myVar_1 = "things";
var myVar_2 = "things";
var myVar_3 = "things";
var myVar_4 = "things";
var myVar_5 = "things";
```

But instead of having to type them 1 by 1, would it work in a loop? I can't seem to make it work and would really love some help/advice on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a dynamic property name using [[ ] array access](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access):

```
var variables:Object = {};

for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++){
    variables["myVar" + i] = "value " + i;
}

trace(variables.myVar3); // "value 3"
```

The `variables` object in this case could be replaced by any [dynamic object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html), including `MovieClips`.

However, in most cases to store data by index it usually makes more sense to use an array. Example:

```
var variables:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++){
    variables.push("value " + i);
}

trace(variables[3]); // "value 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Vector.<String>`, `Array`, `Object` or `Dictionary` for that:

```
var variables:Vector.<String> = new <String>[];
for(var i:int = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    variables[i] = "things";
}
```